# selenium webdriver - detection of the javascript dialogue

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, detection, dialog

Please verify my code for the following URL with credentials as

URL: http://ec2-54-226-18-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com/w/user.html?action=login

username: root

password: 12345678

code:

```
d1.switchTo().window("modalbox");

WebElement select = d1.findElement(By.id("getSelectedCountry"));
List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("Qatar"));

for (WebElement option : options) {
    if("Qatar".equals(option.getText().trim()))
    option.click();   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help,

```
WebElement attribute = driver.findElement(By.id("getSelectedCountry");
attribute.sendKeys("Qatar");
```

Also adding a "wait" After selecting the country can help as it takes times to load

Comment: hey man!!                                                        thanks a lot. this code worked well, at the end i put attribute.submit();        fantastic!

Comment: I got stuck in another step where I want to click one button by the text "add deal", it does not have any id or name just a css, or xpath and I wrote the code as following. please suggest how to make the button click?   //add deal
                        List<WebElement> e2 = d1.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[3]/div/dl/dd/input"));
                        System.out.println("check1");

Comment: TryThis                                                                 WebElement type=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Add Deal']"));
    type.click();

Comment: Depending solely on the Xpath is not a great Idea. Beacuse the application may change in future and so will the way it is placed on the UI. Hence using the Xpath along with some atribute can help. In this case "Value" attribute is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to search the element by "value" and using "By" as tagName. Please use "option" instead. Please check your code as below:

```
    d1.switchTo().window("modalbox");
    WebElement select = d1.findElement(By.id("getSelectedCountry"));
    List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

    for (WebElement option : options) {

    if("Qatar".equals(option.getAttribute("value")))

    option.click();   
    }
```

Comment: hi Nitin,thanks a lot buddy...I tried this code but it did not work for me. I would like to know if there is something missing.